# Can these two regex expressions ever give a different result?

Tags: regex, perl

Can these two regex expressions ever give a different result?

`perl -pe 's/.*c//s'`

`perl -0777 -pe 's/.*c//s'`

Where the `.*c` can be replaced with anything..

In the `.*c` case the result is the same

```
$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nd' | perl -pe 's/.*c//s'
a
b

d

$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nd' | perl -0777 -pe 's/.*c//'
a
b

d
```

And the question re the difference between the regexes, is where what is echoed can be replaced with anything too.

Are `-0777` and `/s` interchangeable?

And is it pointless to do both `-0777` with `/s` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They mean completely different things and are not interchangeable, even though in some cases they can have the same result.

- `/s` makes `.` match all characters (including linebreaks); without it `.` usually means `[^\n]`
- `-0777` means read the whole file at once; without it the file is read line by line

`/s` doesn't change how the input is parsed, `-0` does.

`-0777` is usually only useful if you are matching across several lines (in which case `/s` can be helpful). If you are matching line by line, then whether you use `/s` or not doesn't matter.

For example (using your example), if you would like to remove everything up to the last  `c`, including all the lines, you could use:

```
echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nd' | perl -0777 -pe 's/.*c//s'
```

Output:

```
d
```

Comment: `.*c` removes everything up to the last `c`. If you want the first `c` then you need `.*?c`

Comment: @SidBurn well spotted re qtax's answer.  I hadn't really looked at his example because it wasn't really addressing what I was asking..The reason for my example wasn't really to remove up to the first c or up to the last c. I know how to do both.His answer was decent for what was above his example.  I managed to find the examples I was looking for though, which I put in my answer

Answer (score 2):

Qtax gives a good answer, i'm just going to include some examples to demonstrate they're not the same or even effectively the same.

These two

```
$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nd' | perl -pe 's/./o/s'
o
o
o
o


$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nd' | perl -0777 -pe 's/./o/'
o
b
c
d
```

These two

```
$ echo -e 'aa\nbb\ncc\ndd' | perl -0777 -pe 's/./o/'
oa
bb
cc
dd

$ echo -e 'aa\nbb\ncc\ndd' | perl -pe 's/./o/s'
oa
ob
oc
od
```

These two

```
$ echo -e 'aa\nbb\ncc\ndd' | perl -pe 's/./o/sg'
oooooooooooo

$ echo -e 'aa\nbb\ncc\ndd' | perl -0777 -pe 's/./o/g'
oo
oo
oo
oo
```

Those all demonstrate that -0777 and /s are not the same.

Comment: This would be much clearer without sticking /s and -0777 in the same example.. rather, figuring out each one individually. Then if you want to put them together, fine